# Wordpress ACF - True only on one post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I wanna ask if something that I wanna do is actually possible. I have a custom post type and I have a custom field that is type True/False. What I wanna do is, when you click True on one post, you can't be able to mark another post as True. Is that possible? Alternative would be - when you mark a post as True, if there is another post with True, to set it to False. The idea is only one post to have it set to true. Thank you!

Comment: If you save it as an option, you don't have to save this setting for every post and you don't pollute the post_meta table.

Comment: I actually like to have it for every post, because this True/False checkbox appears based if you checked the checkbox above it. So the case is a little different. If I make it a setting, I would get all the posts, but wouldn't be able to sort them. Hope you got it, I am not good at explaining. @RonvanderHeijden